# FIDE norm chance expectation calculation question

Tags: rating, performance

What is the expected probability that someone rated 2150 will have a performance rating of 2450 over a 9 round tournament and earn an IM norm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the new requirements, I tried to do a calculation. I couldn't find one on the internet suitable for this task, but [this one](https://wismuth.com/elo/calculator.html) suggests that for *one game* between a 2150 and a 2450 player, the following probabilities hold (from the standpoint of the weaker player):

```
win   4.5%
loss 75.1%
draw 20.4%
```

To get a score of 4.5 or more, which is needed to score a TPR of at least 2450, the following results work:

```
5 or more wins              (0.0023%)
4 wins, and 1 or more draws (0.0434%)
3 wins, and 3 or more draws (0.0842%)
2 wins, and 5 or more draws (0.0490%)
1 win,  and 7 or more draws (0.0045%)
            9 draws         (0.0001%)
-------------------------------------
                             0.1835%
```

(you need some combinatorics to get the percentages)

So he will succeed once every 545 tournaments, on average.

<s>It will depend on the strength of the opposition. To take two extremes: if your opponents all have a rating of 1000, you'll always win but never be able to get a TPR of 2450 (9/9 gives a TPR of +700). Conversely, if you're playing nine Stockfishes/Houdinis, rated 3300, you'll score 0/9 but that would give you a TPR of 2600. So the probability you're looking for can be 0%, 100% and everything in between.</s>

Comment: Let's assume average rating of opposition is 2450 and we score 50% for this question.  And yes I believe you also have to play 5 titled players including 3 IM's to be eligible for the IM norm.  There may also be federation requirements of the opponents as well, but I'm not sure of those rules.

Comment: I'm not down voting you, but you should know your examples are very poor and have no bearing on the question. Here are two quotes from the FIDE Title Regulations: "IM performance is ≥ 2450 performance against opponents with average rating ≥ 2230" and "1.42 The following are not included: ... 1.42b Games against computers."

Comment: @BrianTowers the problem was that the question was ill-defined to begin with, and could have all possible outcomes. Now that its scope has been narrowed by the OP, I could provide a reasonable calculation of the probability.

Comment: I like your edit :-). Have an up vote. Yes, somebody who normally plays at 2150 level is a very long way away from an IM norm. Browning: "A man's aim should exceed his grasp, else what's a heaven for?"